# Update database error in python with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to do a function that updates a database through a form but I'm getting this error: `ValueError: operation parameter must be str`.

I have no problem with other functions like delete, read or insert and I don´t know how to fix this problem. 
I put down two versions of function update and respective errors.

I'm trying this:

```
def actualizaDatos():

    Id1 = clave.get()
    nombre1 = nombre.get()
    password1 = password.get()
    apellido1 = apellido.get()
    direccion1 = direccion.get()
    comentarios1 = comentarios.get()


    sentencia="UPDATE DATOSUSUARIOS SET ID= ?, NOMBRE_USUARIO = ?, PASSWORD = ?, APELLIDO = ?, DIRECCION = ?, COMENTARIOS = ? WHERE ID=?", [clave.get()]

    miCursor.execute(sentencia, [Id1, nombre1, password1, apellido1, direccion1, comentarios1])
```

I expected the database to update but I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Practica_Guiada.py", line 148, in actualizaDatos
    miCursor.execute(sentencia, [Id1,nombre1, password1, apellido1, direccion1, comentarios1])
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

Comment: You're setting `sentencia` to a tuple because you have `, [clave.get()]` at the end of the assignment. What is that for?

Comment: One of the query parameters passed to the database in `cursor.execute()` is not of type String although it is required by the database. Have a look at the table definition and at the actual values that are passed to the query and see if the types are valid.

Comment: @jnns it's not the parameters, it's the query string itself which they have made into a tuple for some reason. SQLite doesn't have any type enforcement for primatives

Comment: `, [clave.get()]` remove this from `sentencia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `[clave.get()]` at the end of the assignment to `sentencia`. That's setting the variable to a tuple, not the SQL string.

You also don't have enough parameters in your `miCursor.execute()` call. There are 7 `?` in the SQL, but only 6 elements in the parameter list. You need to repeat `Id1` because it's at the beginning and end (but actually, there's no need to set `ID`, since you'd just be setting it to the same value it already has).

```
def actualizaDatos():

    Id1 = clave.get()
    nombre1 = nombre.get()
    password1 = password.get()
    apellido1 = apellido.get()
    direccion1 = direccion.get()
    comentarios1 = comentarios.get()


    sentencia="UPDATE DATOSUSUARIOS SET NOMBRE_USUARIO = ?, PASSWORD = ?, APELLIDO = ?, DIRECCION = ?, COMENTARIOS = ? WHERE ID=?"

    miCursor.execute(sentencia, [nombre1, password1, apellido1, direccion1, comentarios1, Id1])
```

Comment: Thaks again Barmar, but, why i have to put Id1 parameter at last position?
If i put it the first one doesnt work.

Comment: Variables have to be in the same order as the corresponding `?` in the query. `WHERE ID = ?` is at the end.